# AWS error downloading object from S3, "profile file cannot be null"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897548/aws-java-s3-uploading-error-profile-file-cannot-be-null), but there was no answer to explain my problem. I first used the sample provided [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html) (GetObject class), and it worked immediately on my desktop. However, my friend could not get it to work on his machine, nor will it work on our EC2 instance.

It was mentioned that there are to be credentials files specified, which makes sense, but I never had to do that and am pretty sure the default permissions were set to enable accessing this bucket.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:142)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:133)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:100)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:135)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1049)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:949)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:662)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:636)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:619)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$300(AmazonHttpClient.java:587)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:574)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:446)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4035)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:4474)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:4448)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4020)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1307)
    at GetObject.main(GetObject.java:26)
```

I can guarantee that neither the bucketName nor the key params in the GetObjectRequest are null. What's the discrepancy here? Why might it succeed only on my PC? Is this at all related to the fact that I had to supplement numerous jars that the aws-sdk jar was supposed to have already (jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-annotations, httpclient, httpcore, commons-logging, and joda-time)? It seems similar, what with the otherwise inexplicable errors (giving non-null params, something in aws-sdk says it's null).

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41670728/3770040

Comment: I'm still looking into your link and the "working with AWS credentials" page linked from it, but I never set these-up for my eclipse project and I don't have a credentials file. I'm just running the example out-of-the-box and it works fine. I'm still mystified.

Comment: Ok, I think I identified the issue: I was thinking the credentials would've been stored in the project folder, but I totally forgot about the ~/.aws/credentials file despite reading it in black and white from the question I linked. I just need to know how to set this up for my jar running on my EC2 instance.

Comment: As a general rule, just keep in mind that it is always recommended, in terms of security, to use EC2 roles instead of config files that store user credentials on the instance storage.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It looks like you solved this in the comments, but I got burned on this and want to leave a clearer answer for future readers.  To be super clear, *the problem here has nothing to do with files in S3*.  This error message has *nothing* to do with the file on your hard drive nor the file that you're trying to push/pull from S3. The problem is that you're initializing S3 with something like:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
```

When you do that, it looks in ~/.aws/credentials for a list of profiles. This might work great on your computer but won't work anywhere that you're getting AWS access through an IAM role (ex. Lambda, Docker, EC2 instance, etc).   The fix, is to initialize the AmazonS3Client like:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
```

If you're using code that requires some kind of credentials provider, you can also do:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance());
```

Hopefully that helps the next person.  In my case, I was using DynamoDB and SQS, but I had the same error.  I originally ignored this question because I thought your problem was S3 related and was super confused.  Wrist slapped.

On newer versions of the SDK, you'll need to use following code:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()                  
                      .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                      .build();
```

Answer (score 26):

The top voted answer by Ryan put me on the right track, but since AmazonS3Client is now deprecated, this code has resolved the problem for me

```
    AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                  .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                  .build();
```

This code appears to correctly pick up the active IAM role, say in Lambda.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that the computer of your friend doesn't have the "credentials" file.

To solve the problem, create file:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME \.aws\credentials"
```

for Windows, or create file:

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

for macOS, Linux or Unix.  And then write

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = your_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key = your_secret_access_key"
```

into the file.

Or, you can also set the environment variable of `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`.

Comment: Sorry to forget the preceding [default] at the file header.

Comment: If you're planning on using your code on an EC2 instance, ECS, Fargate, Lambda, etc then this will probably not work for you.  Don't rely on files as the only way to get creds.

Comment: Make sure that the `credentials` file is actually created under the user as whom the program is running; e.g. if your application is a daemon and runs as a user `foo` the file should be in `/home/foo/.aws/`... and if by some odd chance you happen to run with `sudo`, the file should (obviously) be in `/root/.aws/`

Answer (score 1):

I have used following code and working for me , Hope it will helpful

```
       BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey);

            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                    .withRegion("ap-south-1")
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BasicAWSCredentials` might need the all three components as;

```java
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey, accessToken);
```

Also, consider if the credentials are coming from your *.aws* folder OR you are providing as just above, with the `BasicCredentials` line.